# how to execute jQuery callback on $('div.myclass').remove()?

Tags: jquery

I would like to execute a callback after a particular div gets removed.  I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$('div.myclass').remove(function(){
 alert ("div removed");                                 
});
```

Anyone know how to execute such a callback?  I checked the jQuery documentation for remove(), but it does not mention anything about callbacks.  Does this mean remove() does not support a callback?

UPDATE:
Here is a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.  I have a div with class 'nojavascript'.  I want to display this div only if the user does not have javascript enabled.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.nojavascript').remove(); 
  ... // additional jquery commands
});
```

The problem: this div is sometimes displayed to the user for a brief moment, even though javascript is enabled.  It's as though the page is displayed to the user before .remove() finishes executing.  I am trying to ensure that the user *never* sees this div, even for a brief moment, if javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be have better luck using `<noscript>`. This type of thing is exactly what the tag is designed for.

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
...
<noscript>
    <div class="noscript">This doesn't display to users who have JavaScript enabled</div>
</noscript>
<div>
    <p> This displays to JavaScript and non-Javascript alike!</p>
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Any particular reason you can't/don't want to use `<noscript>`?

Comment: OMG+LOL.  "Any particular reason you can't/don't want to use <noscript>?"  Because I didn't know about this.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: It's all good! A book I **highly** suggest is _Javascript: The Good Parts_ by Douglas Crockford. I think you would find it useful! (That's where I picked up the <noscript> 'trick' :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will definitely pick this up.

Answer (score 0):

*Does this mean remove() does not support a callback?*

Yup it means exactly that I'm afraid.

And then.... [jQuery remove() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594817/jquery-remove-callback)

Comment: Oh, that's too bad.  Do you know if there some trick or work-around that would allow me execute a chunk of jquery code only after the div gets removed?

Comment: Yes. Any statement immediately following `$('div.myclass').remove();` will execute when the remove action is complete. This is just normal, synchronous program flow.

Comment: @Beetroot:  It seems that sometimes the code following $('div.myclass').remove(); is executed before remove() is complete.  I will update my question and explain my problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.when($('#qwe').remove()).then(alert('qwe removed!'));
```

Comment: Do you actually understand what you wrote?