# jQuery callback within the remove() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function after a DIV has been removed from the page.

I have tried adding a callback like so, but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
$(foo).remove( function() {
   stepb();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps `remove().done(function(){ stepb() });`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594817/jquery-remove-callback

Comment: Have to ask. Why not just `$(foo).remove(); stepb();`? It is an issue with the context of `stepb()`?

Comment: Jonathan, I want to assure remove has completed before stepb is executed.

Comment: @JasonWells [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is a [synchronous operation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.3/src/manipulation.js#L171-L189). The elements will already be detached from the `document` when it `return`s and before `stepb()` is called.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

<strike>$.when($('#foo').remove()).then(stepb());</strike>
<strike>[**Example1**][1] and [**Example2**][2].</strike>

```
$('#foo').remove();
stepb();
```

​Since the `remove` method in `jQuery` is synchronous, `stepb()` will be invoked after `remove()` has finished. So, no need to use `$.when().then()`.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no event fired when something is removed from the DOM.

Take a look at this question for some good workarounds:  [jQuery - Trigger event when an element is removed from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom)