# Show popup after removing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove div first, then show my popup. But while showing the alert I am able to see the div.
Once closing the popup the div will be removed.

```js
$("#btnRemoveDiv").on("click",function(){$("#divRemove").remove();
alert("Removed");});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="divRemove">Remove this div first then show the popup. Dont show this while the popup is opened!</div>
<input type="button" id="btnRemoveDiv" value="Remove">
```

[image]

@quirimmo Please see this:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/91x9ta3n/3/

Comment: Hi Divya, please add your jsfiddle editing your question, it's easier to check for people who read the question

Comment: Better even: include the relevant code in the question, so the question remains valid even if the fiddle is removed or modified.

Comment: yeah agree. Thanks Peter :)

Comment: Which browser are you testing this on?

Comment: looks like it works to me (Edge and Firefox).

Comment: Working on chrome too.

Comment: Due to asynchronous nature when the `remove()` is run alert is popped up and the alert box takes the focus away from the current window, and forces the browser to read the message. Do not overuse this method, as it prevents the user from accessing other parts of the page until the box is closed. Source - w3schools

Comment: not working in chrome

Comment: what version of chrome do you use?

Comment: Which chrome version did you test this on? And is it chromium?

Comment: also to me it's not working on chrome

Comment: mine is Version 58.0.3029.110

Comment: Same version here and same issue: Version 58.0.3029.110

Comment: Works on 49.0.2623.108. Means it worked before. All solutions will be a workaround then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `when` to manage it as a promise and it should work:

```js
$("#btnRemoveDiv").on("click",function(){
  $.when($('#divRemove').remove()).then(function() {alert('removed');});
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="divRemove">Remove this div first then show the popup. Dont show this while the popup is opened!</div>
<input type="button" id="btnRemoveDiv" value="Remove">
```

JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/91x9ta3n/12/

Comment: nope, this doesnt work with the chrome v58.0.3029.110.

Comment: not working in chrome :(

Comment: could you try the jsfiddle instead of the snippet here please? the jsfiddle seems to work

Comment: jsfiddle works fine

Comment: yeah same here. @divya I have your same version of chrome and the jsfiddle is working fine. The snippet wasn't. Maybe some reason within the snippet functionality

Comment: you used the wrong jquery framework in here (2.1.1) and in the jsfiddle is the jquery 3.2.1. You can add it also in here manually.

Comment: thanks a lot Edwin, trying it right now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105766/jquery-callback-within-the-remove-function

Comment: @Edwin good spot, that was the issue with the snippet. Thanks a million :)

Comment: yes its working for some clicks. But I test it repeatedly and its breaking for some clicks.

Comment: @divya Tried it clicking ten times and it works

Comment: @quirimmo How can I share a snapshot?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki We all know that remove() should be sync. But the example doesn't work. Here a jsfiddle which implements it sync using a function after the remove: https://jsfiddle.net/91x9ta3n/15/

Comment: @divya which version of jQuery are you using? or are you having the issue in my examples too?(here and jsfiddle)

Comment: using same fiddle link provided by you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144646/discussion-between-divya-and-quirimmo).

Comment: weird, It's working always fine to me, tried another ten times :D 
Btw if you will use a timeout, please use just 4ms of delay, no need of half second

Answer (score 1):

Use a timeout so the alert and the remove doesn't execute at the same time.

```
$("#btnRemoveDiv").on("click", function () {
    $("#divRemove").remove();
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("Removed");
    }, 500);
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91x9ta3n/7/

Comment: if you want this solution just put a timeout of the minimum interval, 4ms, no need for half second of delay

Comment: timeout is not a solution

Comment: also, i think there is a typo in your `setTimout`

Comment: @divya - what is it that you are trying to achieve? Because you will see the `div`  if `remove()` is not run before `alert` pop's up as `alert ` forces browser to read the message

Comment: @BhavikPatel I would not like to see the div while showing the poup

Comment: timeout is the only solution because alert stop browser do repaint.

Comment: i dont understand why he doest want to use a timeout...