# I added this timeout function. How can I check if the div is actually being removed or is it just hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my previous code. It only hides the parent targeted container:

```
$(".black-icon").click(function() {
  var taskid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $("#" + taskid).parentsUntil(".container").hide("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 500);
});
```

Here is the `setTimeout` that I added so that it gets removed and not only hidden:

```
$(".black-icon").click(function() {
  var taskid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $("#" + taskid).parentsUntil(".container").hide("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#" + taskid).parentsUntil(".container").remove();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Update: Is there a way I could use the same slide function (jQuery UI) with remove?

Comment: I think no. You can hide and then remove

Comment: So does the timeout addon actually remove the container? How can I check it?

Comment: Check by jquery using something like if (!$('.container').lengt) console.log('not exists');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.hide` has a callback which executes when the animation is finished. You can use that.

```
$("#" + taskid).parentsUntil(".container").hide("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 
  500, 
  function(){
     $(this).remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks man, You are a legend. It worked. Is there a way I could check if the container is removed?

Comment: Container will be removed you dont need to check :P.. Still if you want then do `$(".container").length === 0`

Comment: Is there a way I can get a callback when the remove function is done?

Comment: @ParthAgarwal read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594817/jquery-remove-callback